# What do we call this part of the room?

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call this part of the room?

I am looking for the correct word for this part of the room. I have always called it a “low-roof room”. However, I am not sure whether it is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I think most English speakers would refer to that as a **loft**.

1. loft (n.)
   floor consisting of open space at the top of a house just below roof; often used for storage

[Source](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/loft)

Comment: Loft is probably the most common usage, but balcony might also work.

Comment: Good point. I guess I think of balconies as needing to have an entrance of some kind other than a ladder

Comment: I think of a balcony as strictly outside.  Something inside, like in the picture, is a loft.

Comment: Balconies can be inside, at least in America. The upper level of a theater is called the balcony.

Comment: A [balcony can be inside](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2e/72/60/2e72607380d8c7b6b4acd8d2987f9b0f.jpg), but as @MadGab says it is generally reached from the upper floor to which it is attached, not by climbing from a lower floor (unless you're Romeo).

Answer (score 1):

An intermediate floor is known as a *mezzanine*

Described as: The lowest balcony or forward part of such a balcony in a theater.

A low-ceilinged stor(e)y between two other stories of greater height in a building, usu. built immediately above the ground floor, esp. when the low story and the one beneath it form part of one composition.

Collins English Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we would refer to it as a mezzanine.  I am not presently allowed to up vote otherwise I would have.

Lofts/attics are usually enclosed spaces above the 'living' areas.  Balconies are usually only exterior (unless in very old/large houses).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of **[loft](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loft)** - *a space at the top of a building under the roof used for storing things and usually entered by a ladder, or sometimes made into a room for living in; an upper floor or room*

However, In Russia we call it "**[второй ярус](https://www.bkn.ru/Niedvizhimost/BKN_Daily/3618-10_sposobov_postroit_vtoroi_etazh_v_kvartirie.html)**" - **second storey**, some people call it "**надстройка**" - **superstructure** or "**второй уровень**" - **second level** and I've also heard people refer to it as "**upstairs**".

Such rooms are called "**[two-level rooms](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Two-level%20room&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmn5i-6LrUAhWsF5oKHeOuAFcQ_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=779)**"

Answer (score -1):

Balcony: (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balcony)

Define balcony: a raised platform that is connected to the side of a building and surrounded by a low wall or railing

Comment: This isn't a bad suggestion.  I think it attracted a downvote because of the definition you used.  Neither M-W definition is great for this example, but the second would probably be the better of the two.  The one you picked refers to something external.  Generally, though, a balcony is something that projects out from a wall, overhanging something below.  What's pictured does project out for half the width, so it's arguably a balcony.